highcharts: show tooltip only when hovering over marker
How to make a tooltip for a chart of LINE type displayed only when hovering over a marker (point) of this chart and not displayed when hovering over a curve between two neighbouring markers (points)?
Is it possible to do it within one series, so as not to separate points separately (type SCATTER), and lines separately (type LINE), and customising the tooltip display only when hovering over markers of the same chart type?

Not sure if I fully understand the second part of your question. Here is the demo i have prepared: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zpu3vLbw/ . Let me know if this is what you are looking for!
